# Word Index not in 100% alphabetical order

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Windows 7, Word 2010 & 2016

I have a macro that searches my document for some text, and when found, add that text to an index.  The idea is that I have many definitions (format: `[word] - means [definition]`) and I'd like to throw all these into an Index, so I can effectively have a dictionary at the end.

However, when it runs and creates the index, it's about 90% in Alpha order, but some entries are in random places. As far as I can tell, there's no reason they should be in the wrong order.  (In my section of "A" words, there's a word that starts with "C" or something other than "A").

Here's the clip of the code that's adding them to the index (I pulled this out of a larger macro, but let me know if you want the whole thing):

`myDoc.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=rng, entry:=editedDefinition, entryautotext:=editedDefinition`

`myDoc` is a `Word.Document` (`myDoc = ActiveDocument`).
`rng` is a `Word.Range`
`editedDefinition` is a `String`.

I have a hunch that my line adding to the index is too simple. Does it need more explicit info?

Also, for what it's worth, it seems the index only allows you to add up to some # of characters (it cuts some definitions off for some reason).

Edit: Here's the main macro (you'll notice I call a UDF, please let me know if you need that too):

```
Sub Find_Definitions()
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim oRng As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range
Dim addDefinition$, findText$, editedDefinition$
Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

Call Clear_Index

findText = InputBox("What term would you like to search for?")
If findText = "" Then Exit Sub

'Loop through the document
Set oRng = myDoc.Content

With oRng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = findText
    .MatchCase = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    While .Execute
        Set rng = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range
        rng.Select

        Dim searchText$
        searchText = "- Non- USA"
        If Left(rng.Text, Len(searchText)) = searchText Then
            Debug.Print ""
        End If

       ' Here's where I could check the text, and see if it starts with Roman numerals.
        editedDefinition = Check_For_Roman_Numerals(rng, findText)

    ' Check to see if we're in the 'Definitions' section
    If rng.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber) >= myDoc.Sections.Count - 1 Then
        GoTo TheEnd
    End If

    myDoc.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=rng, entry:=editedDefinition, entryautotext:=editedDefinition

    Wend 'end .execute
End With 'oRng.find

TheEnd:
Set rng = Nothing
myDoc.Indexes(1).Update
MsgBox ("Added all definitions.")

End Sub
```

Edit: (Per comment)
I think I found the issue! After scouring around online, I found [this post](http://raisedbyturtles.org/miscrosoft-word-index-out-of-order#comment-54179) which seems to be my issue! I did a test and removed a semicolon from one of the out-of-order entries, and it put it in the correct place. Now, I just need to figure out how to consider a ; in my adding to Index. I'm still green with Word VBA, so any ideas/tips would be appreciated.

Edit2: Here is my UDFs:

```
Private Function Check_For_Roman_Numerals(ByVal mySelection As Word.Range, searchString As String) As String
Dim romanNumerals() As Variant
Dim firstWord$, paragraphsText As Variant, xWord As Variant
Dim oWord   As Word.Range
Dim i&, x&
romanNumerals = Array("i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v", "vi", "vii", "viii", "ix", "x", "xi", "xii")
Dim editedSelection
Dim moveStart As Variant
Dim myEditedSelection As Variant
Dim addedOnce As Boolean

'editedSelection = mySelection.Text
x = 0
addedOnce = False
With mySelection
    Debug.Print mySelection.Text
    ' Edit selection to include only the start where it's underlined
    On Error Resume Next

    Do Until mySelection.Characters(x + 1).Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle Or mySelection.Characters(x + 1).Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDouble
        If (x + 1) > mySelection.Characters.Count Then Exit Do
        Debug.Print "'" & mySelection.Characters(x + 1) & "' is not underlined"
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set myEditedSelection = mySelection.Duplicate    '= mySelection.moveStart(unit:=wdWord, Count:=x)
    With myEditedSelection
        .moveStart unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=x
        .Select
    End With                 'myEditedSelection
    For i = LBound(romanNumerals) To UBound(romanNumerals)
        If (mySelection.Words(1) = romanNumerals(i)) Or (mySelection.Words(1) = romanNumerals(i) & ".") Then
            Debug.Print "Found roman numeral " & mySelection.Words(1)
            moveStart = trim_Roman_Text(mySelection.Text, searchString, myEditedSelection.moveStart(unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=x) + 1)
            editedSelection = moveStart
            Debug.Print "Adding: """ & editedSelection & """ to Index"
            Exit For
        ElseIf Not addedOnce Then
            moveStart = trim_Text(mySelection.Text, searchString, myEditedSelection.moveStart(unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=x) + 1)
            editedSelection = Trim(moveStart)
            addedOnce = True
        End If


    Next i
End With                     'mySelection

Check_For_Roman_Numerals = editedSelection

End Function


Private Function trim_Text(ByVal myText As String, mySearch As String, startPos As Integer) As String
Dim finalText$
Dim sentenceEndPosition&, meansPos&

meansPos = InStr(1, myText, mySearch)

sentenceEndPosition = InStr(meansPos, myText, ".")
If sentenceEndPosition = 0 Then
    sentenceEndPosition = InStr(meansPos, myText, ";")
End If
If sentenceEndPosition = 0 Then
    sentenceEndPosition = InStr(meansPos, myText, ":")
End If
If sentenceEndPosition = 0 Then
    sentenceEndPosition = InStr(meansPos, myText, Chr(13))
End If
If sentenceEndPosition = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("What is the end of the paragraph?")
End If


finalText = Trim(Mid(myText, startPos, sentenceEndPosition))
trim_Text = finalText
End Function



Private Function trim_Roman_Text(ByVal myText As String, ByVal mySearch As String, startPos As Integer) As String

Dim finalText$
Dim romanNumeralEndPosition&, sentenceEndPosition$, meansPos&
'myText = "i. Australia - means the subcontinent. It is located below Asia, and this is what it looks like. A giant circle with some odd edges."

meansPos = InStr(1, myText, mySearch)

romanNumeralEndPosition = InStr(1, myText, ".")
'Debug.Print romanNumeralEndPosition

sentenceEndPosition = InStr(romanNumeralEndPosition + 1, myText, ".")
If sentenceEndPosition = 0 Then
    sentenceEndPosition = InStr(romanNumeralEndPosition + 1, myText, ";")
End If
If sentenceEndPosition = 0 Then
    sentenceEndPosition = InStr(romanNumeralEndPosition + 1, myText, ":")
End If
If sentenceEndPosition = 0 Then
    sentenceEndPosition = InStr(romanNumeralEndPosition + 1, myText, Chr(13))
End If
'Debug.Print sentenceEndPosition

finalText = Trim(Mid(myText, romanNumeralEndPosition + 1, sentenceEndPosition - romanNumeralEndPosition))
'Debug.Print finalText

trim_Roman_Text = finalText

End Function
```

Comment: Yes it would be good to show the whole thing. Also - what version of word? 2013?

Comment: @Raystafarian - I'm writing in Word 2010.  And I'll add the macros, a word of caution, they're kind of kludgy (so any other advice would be appreciated).

Comment: @Raystafarian - I just tried sorting, after building the index, and it kind of works...but I don't like that, because I get the feeling it's not truly sorting based on the first word of the definition. (I have over 200 definitions, so manually updating the few that are out of sorts is a little too much).

Comment: Can you "show hidden text" and "show field codes" in your document and locate and post the contents of three of the XE fields that are out-of-sequence? (I mean, the XE field that generates an out-of-sequence entry, and the XE fields that generate the index entries that surround it). With any luck, if you do that, it may become obvious how the sequence problem relates to the content of the XE fields.

Comment: @bibadia - Ah, good idea! Unfortunately, the field code looks normal. IE: "Certain Specialist(s) - means ..." appears in the "A" section of the Index, which is incorrect obviously.  When I look at the field code, it is: `{ XE "Certain Specialist(s) - means consultants, ..." }`. I don't see how it's thinking it starts with "A".

Comment: @BruceWayne: I agree. Could be document corruption of some sort?

Comment: @bibadia - Eh, good idea. I've thought the same and checked for that though, but will try again.  For the record, it's going to be 200+ entries, perhaps there's some issue with such a large index? I've Googled around a ton as well, and can't find anything to direct me to this peculiarity.

Comment: If it were my document I would try a few things, e.g. write a small VBA macro to copy all the XE entries (and nothing else) to a new document and see if the generated index had the same problem. Or maybe take a copy, remove half of the document, regenerate index, see what happens, see if any particular part of the document causes a problem.

Comment: @bibadia - Good ideas. I cut the doc. in half, and ran it. The *same* definitions are out of order, and the `XE` code doesn't really lend any hints as to why.  I'll keep chopping up the document/moving things/etc and see what I can do. (I removed all formatting, and the issue still occurs, so it's not that I guess....). I'm new to Word VBA (but am proficient in Excel's VBA), but would I literally just be looking to cut `{` to `}` to get the XE codes? Or is there a better way to search for those?

Comment: @bibadia - I think I found the issue! After scouring around online, I found [this post](http://raisedbyturtles.org/miscrosoft-word-index-out-of-order#comment-54179) which seems to be my issue! I did a test and removed a semicolon from one of the out-of-order entries, and it put it in the correct place.  Now, I just need to figure out how to consider a `;` in my adding to Index.  I'm still green with Word VBA, so any ideas/tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that the semicolon in an index entry markup is a special character that is used to override the sorting. Your link suggests this is a bug, but it appears to be a feature, and it confirms the behavior the individual recounts in your link.

The colon is also a special character and must be escaped with a backslash `\` to use in in text. Presumably, you can escape the semicolon as well. It is pretty common (but not guaranteed) in software and preprocessors that any control characters in a sequence can be escaped.

I cannot quickly find any official documentation about escaping, but [this PDF file](http://www.susandoreydesigns.com/software/IndexingAndWord.pdf) has a decent rundown.

> Built-in sort { XE "Alfonso IV" }
>
> Override sort { XE "Alfonso IV;Alfonso 4" }
>
> Special characters in index entry text  If you need to include a colon
> in an index entry text, “escape” it by preceding it with a backslash
> (like  " Luke 9\:21" ).
>
> If you want to use a symbol, such as @, in the
> index entry text, type “;#” (semicolon followed by the number sign)
> immediately following the symbol.

This [link from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-or-edit-an-index-2070156c-648a-4a9f-aa4d-85265f9cf52f?CorrelationId=3c8d02df-ae33-4ec7-b42d-e7dbec294b4f&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) speaks about the semicolon but doesn't have any information about escaping the colon nor semicolon.

Comment: "Your link suggests this is a bug, but it appears to be a feature..." aren't they all? :P  Thanks a lot for this, I'll look into it and let you know how it goes!  I'll probably want to show my UDF that gets called, as I use it to try to cut down the text, to end at a `:`, `;`, or `.`.